# Horizontal center for custom views

Tags: android, android-layout

For my app I am using the code from https://github.com/namito/TagCloudLinkView/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/ns/developer/tagview/widget/TagCloudLinkView.java *(Line 263 is where the drawing happens)* to create a Tag cloud. The only problem is that the tags are aligned to the left of the screen. How can I center the tags?

The tags now look like, aligned to the left:
[image]

**EDIT:**

I now used LinearLayouts to do the trick, it worked but the margins are ignored. How can I fix this?

The code I am using in the loop:

```
    LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, tagHeight);

    LayoutParams tagParams = new LayoutParams(HEIGHT_WC, HEIGHT_WC);

    if (mWidth <= total + tagWidth + LAYOUT_WIDTH_OFFSET) {
        if(listId != 9000) {
            linearLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastLayoutId);
        }
        listId++;
        linearLayoutParams.topMargin = TAG_LAYOUT_TOP_MARGIN;
        addView(linearLayout, linearLayoutParams);
        lastLayoutId = linearLayout.getId();

        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        linearLayout.setId(++listId);
        linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        tagParams = new LayoutParams(HEIGHT_WC, HEIGHT_WC);
        tagParams.setMargins(TAG_LAYOUT_LEFT_MARGIN, 0, TAG_LAYOUT_LEFT_MARGIN, 0);

        total = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        pindex = index;
    } else {
        tagParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, pindex);
        tagParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, index - 1);

    }

    tagParams.setMarginStart(TAG_LAYOUT_LEFT_MARGIN);
    tagParams.setMarginEnd(TAG_LAYOUT_LEFT_MARGIN);
    total += TAG_LAYOUT_LEFT_MARGIN;
    total += TAG_LAYOUT_LEFT_MARGIN;

    linearLayout.addView(tagLayout, tagParams);
    total += tagWidth;

    index++;
    listIndex++;
```

Comment: put them all in a container layout viz linearlayout and make its `android:gravity = center`

Comment: Good idea, let me try.

Comment: Works! Only thing is that the margins are ignored.. How can I fix this?

Comment: you are not setting margins from top and bottom in your layout params, please tell me if you are not getting margins from any direction

Comment: Vertical margins aren't working either. I used the following line now: `tagParams.setMargins(TAG_LAYOUT_LEFT_MARGIN, 50, TAG_LAYOUT_LEFT_MARGIN, 50);`